# how to get the list of distinct dates and number of records for each date in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I need to get to know the distinct dates in a file and count for each date in unix.
`zcat abcd.log.gz |cut -d'þ' -f1|cut -c1-10|sort|uniq` with this command i am getting distinct dates in a file. but i need count as well.

please suggest me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`uniq -c`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq)

```
... | sort | uniq -c | grep -v <Unwanted text>
```

According to your comment, you are getting an extra "1 Time", so use this exact string after `grep -v`

Comment: i am getting the output like this 496064 11-12-2013 1775 11-13-2013       1 Time. why i am getting 1 time. is there any way to get in grid kind of thing.like sql output

Comment: can we get like this  2013-11-12 | 496064
 2013-11-13 |   1775